# How is best to make database application?

Tags: xml, database, windows

I need to make an application which will read and parse information from xml file and store them to database. What would you recommend?And by that I mean, what do you think is the best programing language for this, what do you think is the best way to work with xml file in this language and what kind of database to use. This database will have to consume from 60 to 300 of new informations per week, and application needs to run also in gui. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are too many answers to this question, but i'll try to give you a hint on where you could go.

If you want XML-capabilities directly on your Databse, then you should have a look at [BaseX](http://basex.org/), a open source XML-Database. The query-language used is called *xquery*. You can make queries on XML-documents and document-collections. There are also Java-bindings for BaseX, so you can implement a GUI in Java and have a persistence-layer connected to the DB underneath it.

So, my combination for a GUI-based Desktop application with access to a XML-Database is Java + BaseX.